# No ICE Candidate with public IP, but WebRTC can still work sometimes

Tags: webrtc, stun

We are testing WebRTC at 3 places A, B and C.

A and C is ADSL, one at home one in office building. B is a company static IP direct line with company firewall and some port filter rules.

The result is: A can connect with both, but B and C can only connect with A.

So we checked their browser console output. A and C can get both internal and public IPv4 candidates (192.168.1.xxx and 123.34.xxx.xxx). B can find 4 ICE Candidate, 2 internal IPv4 candidate (10.0.xxx.xxx) and 2 IPv6 candidate (not sure if the IPv6 address is internal or public).

So the questions are:

1. What is stopping B from getting public IP candidate from STUN server? Is it some port that is blocked by company firewall?
2. B can never get public IP candidate, how did A connect with him? A and B can use WebRTC all the time.
3. Why is C cannot connect with B? Or what is different between A and C? Both of them is using ADSL, fiber modem to TPLINK router (PPPOE dial + default DHCP) to computers, exactly the same.

Thanks.

Comment: One possible answer to #2 is that A is able to receive packets from B, since B has A's public address. Then from the received packet, A makes a "peer reflexive" candidate, and is able to send packets back to the same address it received them from. You could check this in chrome://webrtc-internals ("peer reflexive" means "prflx" remote candidate type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, C is not using ADSL. It's actually an office building provided network with firewall. That's why C cannot connect with B but A can.

Sorry for the mistake, the client "thought" they know their network details.

And thanks to Taylor, you are correct. Only one open network is needed to make WebRTC work.

After hours of research, I figured out the only solution is TURN server. So I think this question can close now.